# What is the object SqlConnection.BeginTransaction useful for

Tags: c#

When I connect to database by ADO.NET. As for SqlConnection object, it has a function: BeginTransaction with 3 overloads. I don't know how to use it and what's its function for?

Answer (score 2):

A transaction ensures a block of work operates in an [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) way - all or nothing.

The optional name is useful for DBAs when tracking long-running transactions. In TSQL *directly* the names are more important, for save-points etc - but in the OO world you have an object for that.

The [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx) determines *how* ACID it is. Serializable is the most pure, but has more overhead costs in terms of additional locks (key-range locks, etc).

Typical usage would be:

```
using (SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) 
{
    try 
    {
        /* work here, assigning "tran" onto
         * any commands */
        tran.Commit();
    } 
    catch 
    {
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

In many ways, it is simpler to use `TransactionScope` - this creates an *ambient* transaction, into which commands enlist automatically. It can also span multiple dbs etc courtesy of DTC:

```
using(TransactionScope tran = new TransactionScope()) 
{
    /* work here; no need to assign tran to anything */
    tran.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A transaction is used to guarantee that a group of actions (sql statements) are either all carried out (a commit) or none are carried out (a rollback).

A typical use is where updates to two or more tables must all succeed (or all fail).